# How to grant NetworkService access to a share by placing computers in security groups

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, permissions, network-share, groups

I'm trying to configure a file share that will be accessed by ASP.Net applications on a set of computers, all running under the NETWORKSERVICE account on those computers.

I can get it to work fine when granting permissions explicitly to each machine account. But I would rather grant permissions to a security group and place the computers in that group. However, the applications keep getting "access denied" when the share is configured with the group.

Shouldn't this just work?

My computers are all in the same Active Directory domain, the application servers running Windows Server 2008 and the file server running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: Have you restarted the computers since adding them to the group (or waited a week, assuming default settings)?

Comment: so the service on the w2k8 service starts up as networkservice, do it as localsystem and place the servername$ in the group you are using for access what happens then?  Also in this case you'd only need to restart the service account for it to work.

Comment: I didn't think localsystem acted as the computer account?